# Request ownership of drive file via Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I know there are lots of questions like that but neither of them matches my issue. I read a lot about changing the ownership of a drive file via API. The chances seem to be possible only if you are either the owner or using a google admin account.

As google provides loads of options I can't a clear sight about possible other solutions.

Thus I wanna ask if there are any chances of setting up a project or making use of a service account (or any other option). Logging in and changing the owner by hand is not an option here.

Important fact: The users involved aren't within the same domain.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we need to be able to see what you are doing.  Yes you cant change the owner of a file unless you are the owner, using a service account with gsuite user delegation would also work, but that would require that this being on the same domain.

Comment: The question is more theoretical. The code to update the owner exists and works.
But what if I have several accounts and I don't want to add credentials for each account to be able to transfer the owner. Thus I was hoping for a smart solution without having all accounts on the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

### Answer

It is not possible to transfer the ownership of a file with a user that belongs to a different domain. If you try to do this from the Drive web version you will receive the following error message:

*Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to something@example.com. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner.*